# Selected date should not be displayed on re clicking date field in date picker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Selected date should not be displayed on re click and i am trying to re click to again this date select

```
 <span class="RegistrationDate">Registration Date</span>
 <div class=" col-sm-8 col-md-4 col-lg-4  input-group date" id="dateofRegistration" style="padding-top: 10px;">
   <input placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker1">
   <div class="input-group-addon" for="datepicker">
     <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
   </div>
 </div>
 <script>
  var date = new Date();
  var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
  var end = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
  $('#dateofRegistration').datepicker({
                format: "dd-MM-yyyy",  //"dd-MM-yyyy",
                todayHighlight: true,
                minDate: 0,
                autoclose: true,
                endDate: '+0d'
  });
  $('#dateofRegistration').datepicker('setDate', today);
</script>
```

Comment: can you explain more your actual requirement its not clear?

Comment: @Vishal Taj PM hi sir, suppose selected date is today date then again this date selected then is not show in date picker

Comment: and if selected date today date and then another date selected then this date is show in date picker -- this is correct